# Could not find stored procedure ''.

Tags: c#, asp.net

below is my code: it is different one from question posted before.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT into test",con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Connection = con;

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileupload1", s1);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", path).ToString();
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Availability",Availability.SelectedValue).ToString();
        [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: there is no stored procedure name in code as I can see

Answer (score 0):

Since the content of your command is a query statement and *not* a stored procedure, use the relevant [enumeration value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// ...
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT into test",con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
// ...
```

But bare in mind your command parameters are unused in this query.

Comment: i follow your answer but another error is shown below  :       Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Answer (score 0):

With the [SqlCommand constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a(v=vs.100).aspx) you are using, the first argument is either the stored procedure name or a query. You have provided a query, but you have set the CommandType to StoredProcedure. Either change the first argument to a stored procedure name or leave the CommandType to the default.